# Interprocess Communication Unix C

Tags: unix, ipc

I have two processes, A and B.  B is a process that performs some functions. Process A is the one that controls B. i.e Process A instruct process B by providing data (control and functional) to it.

I have a thread in B dedicated to IPC, All that thread does is to get instructions from process A while the other threads which are running do whatever they have to with the already existing data.

I thought of pipes and shared memory using shmat. But i am not satisfied, I want something like, whenever Process A writes a msg to B, only then should the ipc thread in B has to wake up.. Any idea as how to acheive this?

Comment: But the problem with it is it also makes the writing proces(A) wait until reading process opens pipe for reading..

Comment: After the pipe buffer is full, that's true.  However, if you don't want to lose any data, it is a necessity to wait for the reader to be ready.  If you don't care about losing data, make the pipe non-blocking.  You could always put another process in the middle of the pipe to act as an unbounded buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I made one of the threads open one end of the pipe for read, do the actual read and close it. This goes on in a while loop which is infinite one!

The process which wants to write to it will open it only when it needs to write and close it and will eventually end.

Infact this setup avoids synchronisation issues as well. But I don know what are the consequences of it though interms of performances!

Answer (score 2):

The specifics sort of depend on what kind of flexibility you need and who is using what pipes, but this should work: Have process B's IPC thread select for readability on the pipe.  When process A writes to the pipe, process B's IPC thread will be awoken.